# Attempt at variadic functions for MSIProcessMessage crashed C++ compiler

Tags: c++, windows-installer

I'm trying to write variadic template functions to help simplify the reporting of errors to MSI from MSI DLL calls. This is my first encounter with variadic functions (I hadn't heard the term before), and so I apparently screwed it up pretty badly seeing as how I crashed the compiler with my attempt:

```
UINT ReportMSIMessage(MSIHANDLE hInstall, INSTALLMESSAGE eMessageType, PMSIHANDLE& hRec, int index)
{
   return MsiProcessMessage(hInstall, eMessageType, hRec);
}
template <typename... Args> UINT ReportMSIMessage(MSIHANDLE hInstall, INSTALLMESSAGE eMessageType, PMSIHANDLE& hRec, int index, TCHAR message, Args... rest)
{
   LRESULT lResult = MsiRecordSetString(hRec, index, message);
   if (ERROR_SUCCESS != lResult)
      return lResult;
   return ReportMSIMessage(hInstall, eMessageType, hRec, index + 1, rest...);
}
template <typename... Args> UINT ReportMSIMessage(MSIHANDLE hInstall, INSTALLMESSAGE eMessageType, PMSIHANDLE& hRec, int index, int value, Args... rest)
{
   LRESULT lResult = MsiRecordSetInteger(hRec, index, value);
   if (ERROR_SUCCESS != lResult)
      return lResult;
   return ReportMSIMessage(hInstall, eMessageType, hRec, index + 1, rest...);
}
template <typename... Args> UINT ReportMSIMessage(MSIHANDLE hInstall, INSTALLMESSAGE eMessageType, Args... rest)
{
   const int argCount = sizeof...(Args);
   if (eMessageType == INSTALLMESSAGE_INFO)
   {
      PMSIHANDLE hLogRec = MsiCreateRecord(argCount-1);
      return ReportMSIMessage(hInstall, eMessageType, hLogRec, 0, rest...);
   }
   else
   {
      PMSIHANDLE hLogRec = MsiCreateRecord(argCount);
      return ReportMSIMessage(hInstall, eMessageType, hLogRec, 1, rest...);
   }
}
```

When I compile, the compiler hangs for quite a while and finally reports:

```
1>  Note: non-fatal system error releasing memory (487)
1>SetupFunc.cpp(1460): fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.
1>  (compiler file 'msc1.cpp', line 1325)
1>   To work around this problem, try simplifying or changing the program near the locations listed above.
1>  Please choose the Technical Support command on the Visual C++ 
1>   Help menu, or open the Technical Support help file for more information
```

Then there are hundreds or thousands of lines line this:

```
see reference to function template instantiation 'UINT ReportMSIMessage<PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,const char*,TCHAR*>(MSIHANDLE,INSTALLMESSAGE,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,PMSIHANDLE,int,const char *,TCHAR *)' being compiled
```

(That's just the shortest of the many lines)

Comment: FWIW, I'm not really a C++ dev... but for MSI C++ CA's you should check out Windows Installer XML. It has a C++ project template that sets everything up and includes a couple reusable libraries. See http://www.joyofsetup.com/2008/07/15/verbose-logging-from-wcautil/

Comment: Also note the release notes for WiX v3.10: http://www.joyofsetup.com/2015/09/07/wix-toolset-v3-10-released/  "DUtil error-checking macros variadic so developers no longer have to think about how many arguments they want in their message beforehand"

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems was that the `TCHAR` parameter should have been `TCHAR *` instead. This might have been interfering with the compiler's ability to pick the right template instance, overload, or whatever you call it, given that I was calling the template function with `TCHAR *` arguments. Another problem may have been the similarity of the argument data types near the end of the list. But I needed to add an `int *` parameter to receive the return value from `MsiProcessMessage` anyway. With these two changes in place, the compiler and code are working much better.

```
UINT ReportMSIMessage(MSIHANDLE hInstall, INSTALLMESSAGE eMessageType, PMSIHANDLE& hRec, int index, int *iResponse)
{
   int response = MsiProcessMessage(hInstall, eMessageType, hRec);
   if (iResponse != NULL)
      *iResponse = response;
   if (response == -1)
      return ERROR_BAD_ARGUMENTS;
   return ERROR_SUCCESS;
}
template <typename... Args> UINT ReportMSIMessage(MSIHANDLE hInstall, INSTALLMESSAGE eMessageType, PMSIHANDLE& hRec, int index, int *iResponse, const TCHAR *message, Args... rest)
{
   LRESULT lResult = MsiRecordSetString(hRec, index, message);
   if (ERROR_SUCCESS != lResult)
      return lResult;
   return ReportMSIMessage(hInstall, eMessageType, hRec, index + 1, iResponse, rest...);
}
template <typename... Args> UINT ReportMSIMessage(MSIHANDLE hInstall, INSTALLMESSAGE eMessageType, PMSIHANDLE& hRec, int index, int *iResponse, int value, Args... rest)
{
   LRESULT lResult = MsiRecordSetInteger(hRec, index, value);
   if (ERROR_SUCCESS != lResult)
      return lResult;
   return ReportMSIMessage(hInstall, eMessageType, hRec, index + 1, iResponse, rest...);
}
template <typename... Args> UINT ReportMSIMessage(MSIHANDLE hInstall, INSTALLMESSAGE eMessageType, int *iResponse, Args... rest)
{
   const int argCount = sizeof...(Args);
   if (eMessageType == INSTALLMESSAGE_INFO)
   {
      PMSIHANDLE hLogRec = MsiCreateRecord(argCount-1);
      return ReportMSIMessage(hInstall, eMessageType, hLogRec, 0, iResponse, rest...);
   }
   else
   {
      PMSIHANDLE hLogRec = MsiCreateRecord(argCount);
      return ReportMSIMessage(hInstall, eMessageType, hLogRec, 1, iResponse, rest...);
   }
}
```

One change that helped to narrow down the problems was changing the function names from `ReportMSIMessage` to `ReportMSIMessageRec` where one of the parameters was a `PMSIHANDLE`. That prevented the compiler from potentially picking the recursive option long enough to tell me why the other templates weren't working out as options.